# Finding the coordinates on the edge of a circle

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry, geometry

Using C#:

How do I get the (x, y) coordinates on the edge of a circle for any given degree, if I have the center coordinates and the radius?

There is probably SIN, TAN, COSIN and other grade ten math involved... :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry is your friend, the calculations are quite simple. Check the Math Namespace for Sin() & Cos()

Comment: That's the kind of question to ask on http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: @Lucero: No, I doubt this one would count as a "research level math question"

Comment: @nikie, true, but on the other hand it's even less a programming question. It's simple geometry.

Comment: -1, not programming related. Voted to close.

Comment: Either way, he would be absolutely flamed to death on Math Overflow if he posted that. They're much more strict about keeping it "by mathematicians, for mathematicians" than we are over here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating point on a circle's circumference from angle in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674225/calculating-point-on-a-circles-circumference-from-angle-in-c)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a geometry question, not a programming question.

Comment: All of these comments are why the StackOverflow websites have a reputation as being unfriendly and hostile to newcomers. Not every programming beginner is good at maths (or even educated in maths!)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Here's the mathematical solution which can be applied in any language:

```
x = x0 + r * cos(theta)
y = y0 + r * sin(theta)
```

`x0` and `y0` are the coordinates of the centre, `r` is the radius, and `theta` is in radians. The angle is measured anticlockwise from the x-axis.

This is the code for C# specifically if your angle is in degrees:

```
double x = x0 + r * Math.Cos(theta * Math.PI / 180);
double y = y0 + r * Math.Sin(theta * Math.PI / 180);
```

Comment: It funny on these types of questions how almost identical the answers are. Even down to the structure of the answer :P

Answer (score 9):

using Pythagoras Theorem (where x1,y1 is the edge point):

> x1 = x + r*cos(theta)
>
>   y1 = y + r*sin(theta)

in C#, this would look like:

```
x1 = x + radius * Math.Cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
y1 = y + radius * Math.Sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
```

where all variables are `doubles` and `angle` is in degrees

Answer (score 4):

For a circle with origin `(j, k)`, radius `r`, and angle `t` in radians:

```
   x(t) = r * cos(t) + j       
   y(t) = r * sin(t) + k
```