# Create any number of divs inside a main div and asssign positions at runtime using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to place many divs in a form of a circle. I will use relative positioning for the divs. For a start I am trying to place four divs around the circle

div 1 - top  50,
left 100

div 2 - top  100,
left 150

div3 - 
top  150,
left 100

div 4 - 
top  100,
left 50

I will be calculating the values in the actual case and setting them but for now it does not matter.Is it possible to create four divs (in an actual case it will be a large number)inside an outer div. But I need to assign differenet sequential ids to these divs and place them at the positions menntioned.

I will have to calculate and then assign top and left positions using script. So could you show how to assign these values using script.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: This may help: finding x-y coordinates along circle

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093405/finding-the-coordinates-on-the-edge-of-a-circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a nice question, as it requires also some math backgrounds.

So, first, let's say what we are going to do: 
  0. you must decide the center of the circle and its radius
  1. we must decide at which angle, on a circle, we should put our divs
  2 we should then make a function which, given the angle, gives you the position of the div

So, what do we do wth all that?

1. decide which should be the center of the circle (if it has to stay in the center of the page
2. decide the radius (could be calculated as well according to windows dimension)
3. some trigonometry: to understand the angle iterval, just divide 360° by the number of divs: if you have two divs, then you angle interval is 360/2=180 (ugly). If you have 10 divs your intrval is 36°

Very good, now we're ready to code.

1. get center: I just redirect you to t it at this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)
2. use the same code to decide tha radius
3. the function which takes, as input, the number of divs, the radius, the center, and gives you back an array with the divs coord. the center is a 2 places array (x and y). In the function we make some adjustment to output the actual postion of the div.

.

```
 function getCoords(divNum, radius, center){
   var num= divNum;
   var angleInt= (6.28/num);
   var outArray=[];
   for (i=0;i<divNum;i++){
    outArray.push([(Math.cos(angleInt*i)*radius+center[0]),(Math.sin(angleInt*i)*radius+center[1])]);
   }
  return outArray;
}
```

Well, it's done, now you can place your divs with any jquery method, like in this example:

```
var localization=getCoords(10,200,[400,400]);

var i=1;
for (var element in localization){
    var posTop=localization[element][0];
    var posLeft=localization[element][1];
    var element= $("<div class='inner'>"+i+"</div>");
    $(element).css({ position: "absolute",
            marginLeft: 0, marginTop: 0,
            top: posTop, left: posLeft });
    $("body").append(element);
   i=i+1;

}
```

hope this helps

Comment: I tried do it as per your answer but it does not seem to work. I have created a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyfrancisjoseph/vVPjH/22/      Could you just take a look

Comment: Managed to get something but not perfect though. Working on it.

Comment: wait a bit, I go and have a look at

Comment: ok go there... something has to be fixed, but you have the idea! http://jsfiddle.net/vVPjH/63/ tell me if you need more help.

Comment: No dont.. I solved it.. It did not work because of a small bug in your function getCoords().. Can you figure it out.. Will post the bug later..I do not whether you had implied that small change was required to make it working..

Comment: Oops sorry..I thought I had figured it out..But now I have a doubt..As you have said 'If you have 10 divs your intrval is 36°'. The for loop is going to be executed 36 times as per you code and will create 36 divs instead of ten. Could you also explain why your code works even though there is no angle to radian conversion in your code. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sin.asp

Comment: Now you find everything working, I aupdate jsfiddle and the answer. As you pointed out we should be using radians and not degrees. http://jsfiddle.net/vVPjH/68/

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        "use strict";

        var NR_OF_ITTERATIONS = 4,
            RADIUS = 40,
            i,
            $wrapper = $("#wrapper");

        for(i=0;i<NR_OF_ITTERATIONS;i+=1) {
            $wrapper.append(
                $("<div/>")
                    .css({
                        top: /* Top position */,
                        left: /* Left position */
                    });
            );
        }
    };
</script>

<style>
    ​#wrapper > div {
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 40px;
       height: 40px;        
    }​
</style>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to generate divs. Put your top and left style in style attr of the div. You can ignore the random number. I used it just as place holder.

```
 <div id="outterDiv" class="outterDivision"> </div>​


var html = '';

        var i;
        for(i=0;i<=4;i++) {
           var Random_Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*500+i);
            html +='<div id="inner'+i+'" class="anything" style="top:50px; left:100px;">'+Random_Number+'</div>';         
        }
        $('#outterDiv').html(html);
```