# How to find the x and y coordinates of a circle given a plot, the original rotation, the new rotation, the origin and radius?

Tags: math, graph, plot, geometry

The easiest way I know how to explain this is with a picture so here it is:
http://pbrd.co/19RxqqV

For simplicity the origin is 0,0 and the angles are easy to work with but they could potentially be anything. The only things I really consistently know for this type of problem is the rotation of the circle, the origin and the radius and then of course the new degree/rotation of the circle.

This question, I think is similar but not really the exact same thing:
[Finding the coordinates on the edge of a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093405/finding-the-coordinates-on-the-edge-of-a-circle)

Thanks! I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: For a general answer, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/rotate-a-point-in-circle-about-an-angle). You can find it by simple equations as described in that post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coordinates of a point with angle a with respect to x-axis on a circle of radius r are:

```
x = r*cos(a*Pi/180), y = r*sin(a*Pi/180)
```

In your case a=45+135

Comment: This seems to be what I need but I'm still running into a few problems.

Sometimes my origin is not at 0,0 what I found though is if I add my original Origin to the equation it seems to set it in the relative area and my point rotates around the circle mostly appropriately.
Like so:
x = originX + r*cos(a*Pi/180), y = originY + r*sin(a*Pi/180)

I'll have to try a little bit more though  because whenever I set the rotation of the circle to 0 then my coordinates for the blue plot end up starting at 180 degrees every time.