# Calculate points coordinates of an arc

Tags: c#, math, geometry

My question is probably more about maths rather than programming, but I hope that is not a problem.
In my app, I am calculating some movement paths, consisting of pixel coordinates (only calculating, not displaying them). I am now trying to smoothen the turn, which are now too sharp, so I would like to use some arc here. I found how I could *draw* the exact arc I need, using code like this:

```
e.Graphics.DrawArc(myPen, myPoint.X, myPoints.Y, 50, 50, 180, 90);
```

Basically what I know are three points (the arc will be between two of these, third is now the turn's corner), the height and width of the arc, the initial and wanted course/heading/angle. I tried this in an app that visualizes the path later, and it works. However, I need to calculate some coordinates on the arc, to add to the array of Points that I save as the path. Anyone knows how? I would need about 5 points for an arc of this size (the number of points will change however)
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674225/calculating-point-on-a-circles-circumference-from-angle-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839899/how-do-i-calculate-a-point-on-a-circle-s-circumference, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300938/calculating-the-position-of-points-in-a-circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DrawArc draws a part of an ellipse or a circle in your case (regarding the 4th and 5th parameter.) The radius of your circle is 25. The math of a circle is: `x^2 + y^2 = r^2`. 
Therefore, I think you can calculate points on this circle by calculating:

```
Y = myPoint.Y + 25 +/- Sqrt(625 - (X - myPoint.X - 25)^2).
```

Let X run from `myPoint.X` to `myPoint.X + 50` and you will find some corresponding Y's.
Because it is a circle, each X has 2 Y values (Therefore, +/- in the formula; you need to calculate the + and the -).

Comment: Note I edited the post for readability with code formatting. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for help

Comment: Hi, what if I need like a hundred points from the arc? How could I do it? I mean, how could I take only points from the arc, and not from the circle