# How to constrain an Jquery-ui's draggable in a circle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, geometry

I want to constrain a controller within an area of a circle with jquery-ui's draggable widget. I write some codes like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
    .draggable {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        border: thin solid #000000;
        border-radius: 40px;
        position: relative;
        top: 110px;
        left: 110px;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    .containment-wrapper {
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        border: thin solid #000000;
        border-radius: 150px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="containment-wrapper">
            <div id="draggable" class="draggable"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
    </script>
</html>
```

The path which the black circle can go along is actually a rectangle, even the appearance of the wrapper `div` is a circle.

How to correct this to fit my purpose?

Comment: See this it could help you P: http://jsfiddle.net/7Asn6/

Comment: this may help (: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314500/constrain-jquery-draggable-to-stay-only-on-the-path-of-a-circle